# Reading from a URL and storing in an ArrayList in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm trying to read from the URL below which appears to work but when I try to store it in the ArrayList it gives me an error. Any ideas on whats causing the error?

```
public abstract class ItemList implements ItemListInterface{

private static String inputLine;
private static ArrayList<String> wordArray;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL wordList = new URL("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18678304/2011/BSc2/phrases.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    wordList.openStream()));



    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        wordArray.add(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
   }
 }
```

Comment: what error message you are getting while storing?

Comment: aaa
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ie.wit.bsc2.autosuggest.ItemList.main(ItemList.java:24)

Answer (score 6):

You forget to instantiate the `ArrayList<String>`.